# showing top bar no matter which tab selected

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am developing iOS project with xcode 8 and Swift 3.

I know how to make tab bar controller, I know how to make navigation controller. But what I want to achieve is something like the following screenshot:

[image]

As you see, there are tabs at the bottom of the screen which means it uses **Tab Bar Controller**, I know how to do that. But the top bar is always showing with only title change to corresponding tab name.

**My questions:**

- How to have this top bar always showing no matter which tab selected?
- Do I need to embed every tab's view into **Navigation Controller** to achieve this? or is there a better way?

**===== UPDATE =====**

Thanks for the answers, I will go with embedding each tab view into a Navigation Controller. But now, I have a new question, what is the best practice to divide them to separate storyboards? and How to divide to multiple storyboards?

Comment: Yes, you have to embed a navigation controller with each tab to show navigation bar. That will make your life easy. If you do not want to add navigation controller then add custom view with labels and other items on your main window & adjust accordingly.

Comment: I also faced similar problem. Embedding each tab view into a Navigation Controller did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve such functionality you have to either insert each tab to navigation controller or you can implement overlapping view that mimics navBar in each tab (which is a bad idea).

Answer (score 0):

Set title of your view controller programatically in each view controller's life cycle methods (viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear) using [title](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621364-title) property of UIViewController.

> [var title: String? { get set }](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621364-title)
>
> Set the title to a human-readable string that describes the view. If
>   the view controller has a valid **navigation item or tab-bar item**,
>   assigning a value to this property updates the title text of those
>   objects.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "view controller title"

    // or you can try one of these
    // navigationBar.topItem.title = "view controller title"
    // self.navigationItem.title = "view controller title"
}
```

You can also, set title property, before you perform push/present operation with view controller.

```
testViewControllerInstance.title = "view controller title"
```

**Answer to Second Que (Updated Que):**

It is good approach to create a separate storyboard for each tab as there would be further navigation flow (more view controllers) associated with root controller of tabbar.

To avoid complexity, you should create separate storyboard for each module (root controller) of tabbar.

There are two ways to create/seprate storyboard:

1. If you already have your view controllers in single storyboard, then refactor your storyboard. 

   **(Xcode Menu Bar) >> Editor >> Refactor your storyboard..**

[image]

2. Create new/separate storyboard.

**(Xcode Menu Bar) >> File >> New >> File >> Storyboard >> Next >> Create**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Insert each tab to navigation controller  will do the trick. And best practice to use everything in a single storyboard . why want to divide them to separate storyboards? it will take more load compared to xibs.

Comment: Because if put everything on the same storyboard, when a team of developers working on it, it could cause merge conflicts. Besides, that it is a best practice in general to have each storyboard represent one view/page, please see this article: https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/xcode-a-better-way-to-deal-with-storyboards-8b6a8b504c06